# Move submit button at the top of from instead of bottom

Tags: drupal

I want to move my drupal form's submit button to top position of form. As by default it always appear at the bottom of every form. but i want it to top position.

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

hook_form_alter is your friend here.

In your template.php file of your theme you want to call YOUR_THEME_NAME_form_alter.

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {  // Targets the specific form.      
        $form['actions']['submit']['#weight'] = 0; // Set this until your button is in the right place. You can include negative integers.
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button where ever you want, just throw this on to a template file for the form.

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['actions']['submit']); ?>
```

And make sure to add

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
```

on the page somewhere near the bottom too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Drupal module called [Content Type Extras](https://drupal.org/project/content_type_extras) that make it easy to add another "Save" button at the top of an edit page. It also includes other extra buttons, such as a "Save and New" button and a "Save and Edit" button.
Best Wishes,
Stephen

Answer (score -1):

By default it will be on the bootom, you can set with CSS, top:px;

> There is another solution for you question, you can use [Arrange
>   Field](http://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) module you can drag and drop component  of you you form.
>   HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU
>   [image]